# how pass a prototype function and use in javascript

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing, prototype, function-parameter

I have a `Graph` class and I want to pass its prototype function to another function. Here is a small snippet code of the class

```
function Graph(opts) {
    this.filled = opts.filled;
    this.max = opts.max || 50;
    this.min = opts.min || 0;
    this.fixed = 60; //px

    this.transitionArr = [];
    this.timeoutArr = [];
};

Graph.prototype.stopAnimation = function() {
    //stop any css3 transition by removing animation properties
    this.removeAnimProps();
    //stop if there is any timeout
    for (var i = 0; i < this.timeoutArr.length; i++) {
        clearTimeout(this.timeoutArr[i]);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < this.transitionArr.length; i++) {
        this.transitionArr[i].stop();
    }
};
```

And what I'm trying to do do is pass `stopAnimation` function to iterate over all objects to stop all animations in all objects:

```
function iterateOverAll(userFunc){
    for (var i = 0; i < GraphArr.length; i++) {
        GraphArr[i].userFunc();
    }
}

iterateOverAll(Graph.prototype.stopAnimation);
```

However, I'm not sure how to do. Any help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use function as argument, you can  pass it like this:

```
function iterateOverAll(callFunc){
    for (var i = 0; i < GraphArr.length; i++) {
        callFunc.apply(GraphArr[i],[]);
    }
}

iterateOverAll(Graph.prototype.stopAnimation);
```

This will call your function across all objects, but without any arguments. I think you can modify this function for any arguments.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know apply has this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have an array of graphs there is no need to pass the function.

```
function iterateOverAll(){
    for (var i = 0; i < GraphArr.length; i++) {
        GraphArr[i].stopAnimation();
    }
}

iterateOverAll();
```

Comment: I know, but I do have many functions like `stopAnimation`. For example, `startAnimation`, `resetAnimation`, `resetGraph` . Therefore, I need to do it in generic way.